# passing variable from php to javascript other than URL method

Tags: javascript, php

I guess the question is as the title suggests, is there a way of passing PHP variables to javascript other than using the URL method. Using sessions wouldn't work either.

The problem is I want my node application to have the data ready prior to connecting to a mongodb database. I have to keep re-loading the screen at the moment when retrieving from mysql and inserting data to mongodb as everything is written in my node application.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies can be used on both PHP and JS.
https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Sockets can be a solution too.

Comment: I don't have php setup in node so I couldn't open an index.php file, I end up with a GET /index.php error

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will probably be the best answer.

```
<script>

var datas = <?php echo json_encode($datas); ?>;

</script>
```

Edit : 
To pass datas from a page to another on different tabs (if this is what you what to do), you can read cookies and check if it's different every X milliseconds. (No tested)

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can just add a hidden input and echo the PHP variable to it's value then select it's value with javascript or jquery

```
<input type="hidden" id="foo" value="<?php echo $var ?>" />
<script>
  var passedValue = document.getElementById("foo").value
</script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, the variable data needs to be sent from one page to another or even one window to another